Problemas al hacer un array javascript
Soy nuevo en el mundillo y estoy practicando creando un array, lo que quiero hacer es aplicarle un event onclick a un boton para que cada vez que escriba un numero en el input se guarde en un array, la cosa es que he creado un array y aparece como si ya tuviese una posición dentro, cada vez que creo otro elemento aparece después del elemento que estaba creado al principio, os dejo el código
const input = document.getElementById("input").value;
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

let array = [];

btn.addEventListener("click", insertarNms);

function insertarNms() {
  array.push(input);

  console.log(array);
}

insertarNms();



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="input" type="number" />

    <button id="btn">Insertar numero</button>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! no entendi tu problema...

He creado un array, y en ese array ya aparece un elemento dentro, en la primera posición, si creo otro elemento el elemento que he creado se va a la segunda posición y asi en adelante. He hecho un console.log para que hay en el array y me sale un elemento vacio: ""

Hay dos problemas con tu código:
Primero, que obtienes el valor que está en el input al cargar la página en una constante, que luego utilizas en la rutina. Sin importar qué el usuario ingrese, siempre vas a estar procesando ese valor almacenado en la constante input. Para conservar tu código, yo dejaría en la constante la referencia al elemento input, es decir el valor devuelto por getElementById.
Luego, que ejecutas directamente una llamada a la función insertarNms en la última línea de tu script, y es esto lo que agrega siempre ese primer valor que ves en el arreglo.
Corrigiendo ambos problemas quedaría algo como:


const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const input = document.getElementById("input");

let array = [];

btn.addEventListener("click", insertarNms);

function insertarNms() {
  array.push(input.value);
  console.log(array);
}
<input id="input" type="number" />
<button id="btn">Insertar numero</button>




Estas haciendo una llamada innecesaria a la función insertarNms(); en el final de tu código JS, elimínalo y solucionaras el problema.
Tu código JS quedaría así:


const input = document.getElementById("input");
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

let array = [];

btn.addEventListener("click", insertarNms);

function insertarNms() {
  array.push(input.value);

  console.log(array);
}
<input id="input" type="number" />
<button id="btn">Insertar numero</button>



Espero te sirva.

Además, debería recuperar el valor del input cada vez que se llama a la función, sino siempre va a guardar el mismo valor.
